# Showing that a k-cell is totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove that a k-cell or cube of the form $T$ = $[-b,b]$ x $\cdots$ x $[-b,b]$ for some $b > 0$, is totally bounded. The reference that I am looking at suggests the balls $B(\epsilon  j;\epsilon)$, where $j = (j_1, ..., j_n)$ ranges over all integral lattice points of $R^n$ which satisfy $\epsilon|j_i| \le 2b$, $1 \le i \le n$. I understand intuitively that these balls cover $T$ but I can't show rigorously how they must cover the cube. Can anyone help me out why such a setting suffices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $k=n$ for simplicity so that $T = [-b,b]^n$. The sidelength of $T$ is $2b$, so by subdividing each side into $k$ equal subintervals you can write $T$ as a union of $k^n$ cubes of sidelength $\dfrac{2b}{k}$. In turn, each subcube can be covered by a single ball of radius $\dfrac{2b}{k}\sqrt{n}$ (this bound can be improved but the improvement is not important for this argument).

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $k$ so large that $\dfrac{2b}{k} \sqrt{n} < \epsilon$. Then $T$ can be covered by $k^n$ balls with radius less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: why is the radius of the ball $\dfrac{2b}{k}\sqrt{n}$
 not just $\dfrac{2b}{k}$?

Comment: As I mentioned the bound isn't the best. I used the diameter of the cube for the radius.